# Understanding how Django Apps system works

Tags: python, django, django-apps

After some months of using Django, I feel the need to create the first my Django application. In this way I can really take the advantages of the Django's power.

Someone can give me hints and directions for learning well about it?

How Django's apps system works? And how can I create my first reusable app?

I think Django's is one of the best framework ever created and I want to learn it very well for using it in various contexts.

And now I would to take my Django's experience and skills to the next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the official Django documentation and tutorial, which are excellent, I would recommend two books you should check out:

Ayman Hourieh's Django Web Development 1.0:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/1847196780/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/191-3941588-1909500](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196780)

An awesome book that will take you step by step through creating your first Django app, and that touches on several of Django's features and functionality.

The Definitive Guide to Django:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/1847196780/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/191-3941588-1909500](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196780)

The title says it all, written by Django's creator and lead developer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss a great talk about reusable apps by James Bennet: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4 .

Answer (score 0):

Try here for starters:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

> This document describes Django 1.3.
>   Writing your first Django app, part 1...

And I suggest you go to Amazon.com, look through Django books and read a lot of the reviews until you find something that sounds appropriate for you.

HTH